# How to 301 redirect sub domain post URL to root domain

Tags: redirect, wp-redirect

We have a subdomain which is implemented in WordPress: https://blog.aisee.co.in/ and it has more than 2000 posts in it.

As per SEO perspective, we wanted to migrate the subdomain to the main root domain: https://www.aisee.co.in/

So we created a folder/directory where we want to migrate subdomain post articles: https://aisee.co.in/scholarship/ (it is also in WordPress)

Keeping [SEO Ranking Factors](https://searchenginelaws.com/article/seo-ranking-factors/) in mind, We want to 301 redirect the subdomain url to new url: For Example -

We wanted to Redirect: 
https://blog.aisee.co.in/manipal-university-dr-tma-pai-scholarship/ 
to 
https://aisee.co.in/scholarship/manipal-university-dr-tma-pai-scholarship/

Currently, we have imported all the subdomain articles to the root domain and there are more than 2000 URL need to be 301 redirected.

Instead of manually redirecting each URL, I wanted to know if there is any pattern matching or easy way to redirect all these URLs at once.

If there is an easy way out either through a plugin or through code then please do let know. It would be very helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: Check over on Stack Overflow. There is likely an answered question that will show you what to put in .htaccess. Also, keep in mind: the fact that you're moving all these posts will impact your SEO negatively. You'd likely be better off building more links between subdomains instead of actually moving that much content. And, if you really want search engines to think it's all a single site, make sure that the WP URL can only be accessed at `www.example.com/wpurl` since you are using `www.example.com`. If you have set it up at `example.com/wpurl` with no "www" search engines see it differently.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into it

Answer (score 0):

The Webmasters' StackExchange has [a solution](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/13475/redirect-rewrite-subdomain-to-subfolder#13493) that sounds perfect for you.

Below, I have adapted it to your specific request.  Hope this helps!

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www)\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.aisee\.co\.in [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://aisee.co.in/scholarship/%1 [R=301,L]
```